# how to clear Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client table structure cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle-manageddataaccess

Here's an ASP.NET MVC Core action:

```
public ActionResult<object> Try()
{
    OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection)_context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from mytable fetch first 1 rows only";

    var result = new List<string>();
    using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            result.Add(reader.GetName(0)+": "+reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
    return string.Join(',',result);
}
```

Then do the following:

1 create and fill table:

```
create table mytable (f1 number(10), f2 varchar2(10));
insert into mytable values (32,'32');
grant select on mytable to myuser;
```

2 call the Action:

```
http://localhost/MyController/Try
// output is okay:
// F1: 32
```

3 then:

```
alter table mytable add f3 varchar2(5) default ('f3') null;
```

4 call Action again:

```
http://localhost/MyController/Try
```

This throws an exception in OracleCommand.ExecuteReader:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Internal Error
  Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
  StackTrace:
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFetchSize, Int64 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64 initialJSONFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean bAllInputBinds, Int32 arrayBindCount, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]& rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean& bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, List`1& implicitRSList, Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, Int64 internalInitialJSONFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Restarting the application solves the problem.
It seems that ManagedDataAccess caches table structure somewhat.

The aim is make it work without restarting the application.
How to do that? Is it necessary to clear some caches somehow?

Comment: Commands are `IDisposable` too IIRC. Does it make a difference if you use a `using` block for cmd too?

Comment: @Zastai : thank you for pointing out OracleCommand is IDisposable. But unfortunately, encapsulating the command in a using block didn't make any difference, the same exception is raised after adding a column.

Comment: Then if your API needs to be robust against such an error, I would suggest opening a fresh connection for each request (assuming the caching is at the connection level), even if that might not be great for performance. Or catching the exception and retrying it (once) using a fresh connection.

Comment: Although I see that OracleConnection has a `PurgeStatementCache()` method. Does that have any effect? Similarly, OracleCommand has an `AddToStatementCache` property; if that defaults to `true`, does it help to set it to `false` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Zastai, solution has been found: statement cache.

```
oracleCommand.AddToStatementCache = false;
```

makes it work even if table structure changed or table deleted/recreated.

Comment: you should accept your own answer here because this is not a bad thing to have. someone just asked same question.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and solved it using the
[PurgeStatementCache](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle//oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/ConnectionPurgeStatementCache.html) method:

```
conn.PurgeStatementCache();
```

This has the benefit of allowing statements to be cached (for performance) at the cost of having to explicitly purge the cache when cache busting changes have occurred.